# How to provide LineNumbers to the given text in wrapped mode

Tags: java, swing, awt, document, jtextarea

I had wrote LineNumbers logic for text in `JTextArea`. It is working fine whenever enter some text and enable the Viewlinenumbers. But, I enter some long line of text with multiple lines then I enable wordwrap action first, then I enable ViewLineNumbers, It's not working correctly.
Please check it once.

Here is code:

```
public class ViewLineNumbers extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  int i=0;
  JTextArea textArea,lnNum;
  JScrollPane scrollPane;
  public ViewLineNumbers() {
    initComponents();
    viewLineNumbers.setSelected(false);
    wordWrap.setSelected(false);
  }
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
  private void initComponents() {

    tabbedPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    menuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    file = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    newAction = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    viewLineNumbers = new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem();
    wordWrap = new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    file.setText("File");

    newAction.setText("New");
    newAction.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            newActionActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    file.add(newAction);

    viewLineNumbers.setSelected(true);
    viewLineNumbers.setText("ViewLineNumbers");
    viewLineNumbers.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            viewLineNumbersActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    file.add(viewLineNumbers);

    wordWrap.setSelected(true);
    wordWrap.setText("WordWrap");
    wordWrap.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            wordWrapActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    file.add(wordWrap);

    menuBar.add(file);

    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
  }// </editor-fold>

  private void newActionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("");
    i++;
    internalFrame.setName("Doc "+i);
    internalFrame.setClosable(true);
    internalFrame.setAutoscrolls(true);
    textArea=new JTextArea();
    textArea.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 13));
    scrollPane=new JScrollPane(textArea);
    internalFrame.add(scrollPane);
    tabbedPane.add(internalFrame);
  }

  private void wordWrapActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) evt.getSource();
    if (button.isSelected()) {
         textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    }
    else {
          textArea.setLineWrap(false);
    }
    textArea.revalidate();
  }

  private void viewLineNumbersActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) evt.getSource();
                  if(button.isSelected()){
                    lnNum = new JTextArea("");
                    lnNum.setEditable(false);
                    lnNum.setSize(50,50);
                    lnNum.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 13));
                    lnNum.setText(getText());
                    textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
                     @Override
                     public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                     lnNum.setText(getText());
                  }
                @Override
                 public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                 lnNum.setText(getText());
                }
                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                lnNum.setText(getText());
                }
             });
                   scrollPane.getViewport().add(textArea);
                   scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(lnNum);
                   }
                   else{
                       scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(null);
                   }
  }
  public String getText(){
    int caretPosition = textArea.getDocument().getLength();
    javax.swing.text.Element root = textArea.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
    String text = "1" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    for(int i = 2; i <=  root.getElementIndex( caretPosition ) + 1; i++){
        text += i + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }
    return text;
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ViewLineNumbers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ViewLineNumbers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ViewLineNumbers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ViewLineNumbers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ViewLineNumbers().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
  }
  private javax.swing.JMenu file;
  private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuBar;
  private javax.swing.JMenuItem newAction;
  private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
  private javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem viewLineNumbers;
  private javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem wordWrap;
}
```

Comment: See http://www.java2s.com/Questions_And_Answers/Swing/JTextArea/number.htm

Comment: I had tried your provide link but not working for me.In my application logic is working fine.But,after wordwrap only it shows some improper view of lineNumbers.once run and check it my program.